# Example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial_{u}f \neq \nabla f.\vec{u}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Is there an example of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\partial_{u}f \neq \nabla f\cdot u$$

for all unit vectors $u$?

I'm trying to find an example. I already know that it can not be a differentiable function, otherwise the equality always holds. Any tips?

Comment: Re: it cannot be differentiable: what does $\nabla f$ mean for a non-differentiable function?

Comment: Just $\nabla f = (f_x, f_y)$, so I want a function where $\partial_u f \neq u_1f_x + u_2f_y$, in which $u=(u_1,u_2)$.

Comment: How about $ f(x,y) = x $ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise, then $f_x(0) = f_y(0) = 0$ but for $u \propto (1,1),\  \partial_u f(0) \neq 0 $?

Comment: That's a great example, much simpler than the ones I was trying to think, thanks a lot @CalvinKhor.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was 'too simple' for you. :) Have now posted it as an answer

Comment: A simple example is always better :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the comments: an example is
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} x & x=y \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
This $f$ is continuous at $0$, and Gateaux differentiable at $0$. Notice $f(x,0) = f(0,y) = 0$ for all $x,y$, so $f_x(0)=f_y(0) = 0$. Yet, for $u\propto (1,1)$, $\partial_u f(0) \neq 0$.